# Debug route provided to routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am new to AngularJS and am attempting to debug some of my routes but I don't know how to display/view the route passed to the routeprovider.

For example if my current routing is set up as follows;

```
reportFormsApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Reporting", { templateUrl: "ReportForm/rfTemplate.html", controller: "rfController" })
        .when("/Dashboard", { templateUrl: "DashboardForm/dfTemplate.html", controller: "dfController" })
        .when("/Analysis",  { templateUrl: "AnalysisForm/afTemplate.html", controller: "afController" })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Reporting" })
});
```

When debugging I want to break the code and in the console log enter something like;

```
$routeProvider.path
```

to display the route as it would be evaluated by the ".when".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can listen to multiple events emitted by the [`$route service`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route). These events are:

- `$routeChangeStart`
- `$routeChangeSuccess`
- `$routeChangeError`
- and, `$routeUpdate`

(I would encourage reading the docs provided by the link for descriptions of each.)

At this point you can listen for one or all of these events on the `$scope` of one of your controllers or directives, or by injecting `$rootScope` into your `angular.module().run()` function or another service/factory.

For example, as an addendum to your provided code:

```js
reportFormsApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/Reporting", { templateUrl: "ReportForm/rfTemplate.html", controller: "rfController" })
    .when("/Dashboard", { templateUrl: "DashboardForm/dfTemplate.html", controller: "dfController" })
    .when("/Analysis",  { templateUrl: "AnalysisForm/afTemplate.html", controller: "afController" })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Reporting" })
});

reportFormsApp.run([
  '$rootScope',
  function($rootScope) {
    // see what's going on when the route tries to change
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
      // next is an object that is the route that we are starting to go to
      // current is an object that is the route where we are currently
      var currentPath = current.originalPath;
      var nextPath = next.originalPath;

      console.log('Starting to leave %s to go to %s', currentPath, nextPath);
    });
  }
]);
```

You can also access the rest of your `$routeProvider` objects as well such as `current.templateUrl` or `next.controller`.

**Note concerning redirectTo:**
There is one object exception to using the `$route service` events and that is when there is a redirect. In this case, `next.originalPath` will be undefined because all you will have is the `redirectTo` property you defined in `otherwise()`. You will never see the route that the user tried to access.

So, you can listen to the [`$location service's`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) `$locationChangeStart` or `$locationChangeSuccess` events:

```js
reportFormsApp.run([
  '$rootScope',
  function($rootScope) {
    // see what's going on when the route tries to change
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
      // both newUrl and oldUrl are strings
      console.log('Starting to leave %s to go to %s', oldUrl, newUrl);
    });
  }
]);
```

If you use HTML5Mode then there will be two other arguments provided by the `$locationChange*` events. Those are `newState` and `oldState`.

In conclusion, listening to the `$route*` events will likely be your best bet for debugging objects and definitions you provide in your `$routeProvider`. However, if you need to see all url's being attempted, the `$locationChange*` events will need to be listened to.

*Current as of [AngularJS 1.3.9](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/docs/api/)*

Comment: Thanks Stephen - this allowed me to resolve my issue.